# extract relevant subgraph of a resource

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

Is there a way to extract a relevant subgraph of a resource and then storing it in a Jena object ?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question.  In RDF, a resource is not a graph.  A graph is a collection of triples. A resource is a node in a graph. What do you mean by a "subgraph of a resource"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In SPARQL, you can extract a subgraph using a [CONSTRUCT](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) query. For example, to get a subgraph of all resources of type `:Foo` you could do something like this:

```
 CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o }
 WHERE { ?s a :Foo ; ?p ?o .}
```

Alternatively, you can use [DESCRIBE](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) to get a subgraph describing specific resources, e.g:

```
 DESCRIBE <http://example.org/your/mum>
```

However the precise behaviour of DESCRIBE is not standardised, so depending on the toolkit/triplestore you use you may get slightly different results.

I can't help you with the Jena-specific part of your question but I imagine that adding the result of a CONSTRUCT/DESCRIBE into a model is very straightforward.

Comment: Perfect I tried to use the construct.  But Does the result consist in a big graph containing the relevant subgraphs of every tuple? Do these sugraphs are linked each other ?

Comment: @user2837896 If you want all the triples that have `x` as subject or object (and, in general, predicate) just ask for them: `construct { <x> ?p1 ?o1 . ?s2 <x> ?o2 . ?s3 ?p3 <x> }`.  That will include all the triples in which the resource appears.